# Android - ProgressBuilder goes behing my RoboDialogFragment?

Tags: android, roboguice

I have the following Dialog progress. This dialog progress is being Injected into the activity/fragments as needed. When I display this in an Activity it works perfectly fine.
But when I try to show it inside a fragment in an activity it shows up below the dialog.

Any way to fix this class to show the progress dialog correctly, `without having to manually pass the context to this class?`

Progress Dialog Class

```
public class ProgressBuilder implements IProgressBuilder {

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Inject
    public ProgressBuilder(Provider<Context> contextProvider) {
        this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(contextProvider.get());
    }

    public void show() {
        this.show("Loading...", null);
    }

    public void show(String message) {
        this.show(null, message);
    }

    public void show(String title, String message) {
        this.progressDialog.setTitle(title);
        this.progressDialog.setMessage(message);
        this.progressDialog.show();
    }

    public void dismiss() {
        this.progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Activity Class

```
public class MyActivity extends RoboFragmentActivity {

@Inject IProgressBuilder progress

}
```

This Fragment is shown on MainActivity

```
public class MyActivity extends RoboDialogFragment {

@Inject IProgressBuilder progress

}
```

Comment: You really should be using a DialogFragment for this.

Comment: @ChristopherPerry Can you provide an example please? I've read that on other threads already but no-one points how I could be using a DialogFragment for this reason

Comment: There's a ton of examples in the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

Comment: @ChristopherPerry I've seen all those samples, but based on those samples the purpose of a DialogFragment is to display more content in as a modal on top of current activity, which I am already doing. Are you sure it's a good idea to create my own Progress as a subclass of a DialogFragment instead of using the default class provided by android?

Comment: You don't subclass DialogFragment with ProgressDialog, you wrap a ProgressDialog with a subclass of a DialogFragment. Use the example from the docs where they are wrapping an AlertDialog, and replace that with a ProgressDialog and you're set. You should always favor composition over inheritance.

Comment: @ChristopherPerry thanks for the response. Just add your comment as a response so that I can select it as best answer. I'm curious what the the reason behind not using a DialogBuilder directly? Is it no compatible with fragments? or is there any other reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really should be using a DialogFragment for this.

There's a ton of examples in the documentation:

[developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

You would simply wrap a ProgressDialog with a subclass of a DialogFragment. Use the example from the docs where they are wrapping an AlertDialog, and replace that with a ProgressDialog and you're set.